# Is the Axiom of Choice needed here, when looking into the properties of an element of a set?

Tags: set-theory, axiom-of-choice

I understand that the Axiom of Choice is used when making choices from an infinite set or making a choice each from an infinite number of sets. Would it be used in the following situation:

$A \cap B \neq \varnothing$. Therefore, there is some $x \in A \cap B$, meaning $x \in A$, $x \in B$.

My question is - if $A \cap B = \infty$, do you need the Axiom of Choice to be able to even consider $x$, or is this more of a hypothetical consideration of all elements that fall into this category without actually picking anything out?

More generally, **how do I know for certain if the Axiom of Choice is being used?**

EDIT: https://faculty.washington.edu/smcohen/120/Chapter12.pdf helped me get existential instantiation, which answered my question.

Comment: You don't need the axiom of choice when you choose from one set.

Comment: You might want to look up [existential instantiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Existential_instantiation). Elementary books on "Foundations of Mathematics" call this principle "Name It, then Use It".

Comment: Thanks Lee. This [link](https://faculty.washington.edu/smcohen/120/Chapter12.pdf) helped a lot.

Comment: No.... You are told that $A\cap B$ is not empty. That means it has at least one element.  You may refer to an arbitrary element by a variable name (but you can't assume anything about the element other than it exists).  That is not an application of the axiom of choice.